# My editing software calls out an error "initial -ing"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

ProWritingAid software flags the following type sentences as an error called initial -ing.

> Frowning, he rose and walked in his bare feet to the door.

I've tried to find a grammar rule that prohibits such usage, but have been unsuccessful.

Can someone explain the problem to me?

Comment: It might call it out because phrases like that are often [dangling participles](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/dangling-participles?page=1), although in this case it isn't.

Comment: My spell check often objects to British spellings of words - but that doesn't mean it's correct: it just isn't trained properly!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the people writing the program. There is nothing grammatically wrong with what CGEL labels supplements (which include ing-forms [called gerund-participles by some] and participle clauses). Very light ones, however, are not usually idiomatic. And the usual constraint on not putting disparate statements in the same sentence applies.

> */? Sad, he rose and walked in his bare feet to the door.
>
> */? Tired, he rose slowly and walked in his bare feet to the door.
>
> Tired after all his exertions, he rose slowly and walked in his bare
>   feet to the door.
>
> Exhausted, he rose slowly and walked in his bare feet to the door.
>
> */? Crying, he rose and walked in his bare feet to the door.
>
> Crying because of the terrible pain, he rose and walked in his bare
>   feet to the door.
>
> *His holidays approaching, he rose and walked in his bare feet to the door.
>
> His mind racing, he rose and walked in his bare feet to the door.
>
> [* = unidiomatic here rather than ungrammatical]

Even though *frowning* is a light supplement, unlike *crying* it is acceptable here. This is possibly because it is a more volitional verb; *smiling* also works whereas *worrying* really needs say *about who this might be at this hour*.